# I have a problem connecting to Tor network

Tags: network-configuration

this is the data it shows, please help!
thanks

3/18/2018 00:44:41.500 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
3/18/2018 00:45:24.400 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
3/18/2018 00:45:24.400 [NOTICE] Switching to guard context "default" (was using "bridges") 
3/18/2018 00:45:24.400 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
3/18/2018 00:45:24.400 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
3/18/2018 00:45:24.400 [NOTICE] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
3/18/2018 00:45:24.400 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 5%: Connecting to directory server 
3/18/2018 00:45:24.400 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 10%: Finishing handshake with directory server 
3/18/2018 00:45:48.600 [WARN] Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 10%: Finishing handshake with directory server. (DONE; DONE; count 10; recommendation warn; host FC9AC8EA0160D88BCCFDE066940D7DD9FA45495B at 86.59.119.83:443) 
3/18/2018 00:45:48.600 [WARN] 10 connections have failed: 
3/18/2018 00:45:48.600 [WARN]  10 connections died in state handshaking (TLS) with SSL state SSLv2/v3 read server hello A in HANDSHAKE 
3/18/2018 00:45:48.700 [NOTICE] Closing no-longer-configured Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
3/18/2018 00:45:48.700 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
3/18/2018 00:45:48.700 [NOTICE] Closing old Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
3/18/2018 00:45:49.500 [NOTICE] Delaying directory fetches: DisableNetwork is set.

Answer (score 0):

Seems your ISP very loyal :D If you use expert bundle add in torrc [bridges](https://bridges.torproject.org/bridges?transport=obfs4) or configure [browser](https://tb-manual.torproject.org/en-US/circumvention.html)